# Getting a 'Path Error' with nested forms Array

Tags: javascript, html, angular, forms

I have the following html:

```
<form [formGroup]="customFieldForm">
                 .......... 
      <div formArrayName="FieldNames">
           <div *ngFor="let fieldName of customFieldForm.get('FieldNames').controls; let i = index" 
           [formGroupName]="i">
               <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput [value]="fieldName.value.CustomFieldName"
                [formControlName]="CustomFieldName"
                [placeholder]="placeHolderInLocalLanguage">
          </mat-form-field>
       </div>
    </form
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Cannot find control with path: 'FieldNames -> 0 (and all the length of the array...) ->
```

the TS file :

```
        this.customFieldForm = new FormGroup({
        Menu: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
        FieldType: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
        FieldNames : new FormArray([]),
        OptionalOrMendatory: new FormControl(false),
        LineTypes: new FormControl(null),

    })
```

the Initiation Of data from server:

```
this.data.forEach(nameAndLanguage => {
const FieldName: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    CustomFieldName: nameAndLanguage.CustomFieldName,
    ID: nameAndLanguage.LanguageID
});
(<FormArray>this.customFieldForm.get('FieldNames')).push(FieldName);
})
```

Any one can spot what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks to anyone trying to help in advance!

Comment: Try `<div formArrayName="FieldNames" *ngIf="ustomFieldForm.get('FieldNames').controls"></div>`

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't seems to be the problem :( but thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my issue :

```
 [formControlName]="CustomFieldName"
```

tried by mistake to bind to a property.